# Autohotkey paste snippet with HTML link

Tags: html, autohotkey

seem simple, but couldnt figure it out. how to paste this snippet with AHK so that user only see "link" word with hyperlink ?

[link](https://www.html.it/).

Comment: In which program?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put it into clipboard ('copy') as the formatted text from somewhere first. The place to get it from can be constructed with AutoHotkey, but it's not simple.

Some examples from here:
https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=79535

```
FilePath := "C:\Autohotkey\test.docx"

F12::
oDoc := ComObjGet(FilePath)
oDoc.Range.FormattedText.Copy
oDoc.Close(0)
Send, ^v
return
```

(obviously, you'll have to construct `test.docx` to make it contain the link).

Alternatively, use [`WinClip` library/class](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/74670-class-winclip-direct-clipboard-manipulations/) to construct the link:

```
; https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/74670-class-winclip-direct-clipboard-manipulations/

#Include <WinClipAPI>
#Include <WinClip>

PasteText::
    WinClip.Clear()
    WinClip.SetText("link: https://www.html.it/.")
    WinClip.SetHTML("<a href=""https://www.html.it/"">link</a>")
    WinClip.Paste()
return
```